# How do I show services in Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, developer-tools

I want to add my services to my WordPress website.
I try my Elementor Pro but I need a widget to customize more the service tab on my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Essential Addons for Elementor plugin, which provides a wide range of widgets and custom modules for Elementor, including a Services widget. This plugin can help you add and customize service tabs on your WordPress website using Elementor with ease.